# File with no extension not changing on powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting, powershell-ise

I have the following code:

```
Get-ChildItem . *. | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace 'line21','line21.map52'}
```

producing this error:

```
file: line21 is currently of type File (No extension).
```

When trying to change it to another extension it does not change.

However for the same scenario, it works perfectly fine if I took another file:

```
Get-ChildItem . *. | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace 'line22.txt','line22.map52'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is happening, because your `Get-ChildItem` command is only retrieving files/folders whose names match `*.`. The file name "line21" does not match `*.` so it is being excluded.

Change your command to this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Include * | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace 'line21','line21.map52'};
```